Customizing Drag Preview with Thumbnail Images in React-DND: Seeking Guidance for Enhanced Drag-and-Drop Functionality
I'm implementing a drag-and-drop functionality in my React application using libraries like react-dnd. While the basic drag-and-drop functionality is working fine, I'm now facing a challenge where I need to customize the drag preview to display additional information from the dragged item.
Specifically, I want to show a thumbnail image alongside the default drag preview, which currently only displays the item's name. I've explored the documentation for react-dnd but haven't found a straightforward way to achieve this customization.
Could someone provide guidance or a code example on how to customize the drag preview in react-dnd to include additional elements like thumbnail images? Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
